# How to implement Stopwatch functionality in extjs4[MVC]

Tags: model-view-controller, extjs, stopwatch

I want to implement stopwatch functionality in extjs4 with start timer and pause timer events. I searched lot but not getting how to implement it in Extjs4 MVC format. What do I need to include as xtype in view? How do I need to process it?

Comment: What have you already tried? Show us your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **Ext.TaskManager** to start and stop arbitrary tasks. [See Reference](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.0.7/#!/api/Ext.TaskManager)

```
// Start a simple clock task that updates a div once per second
var task = {
run: function(){
    Ext.fly('clock').update(new Date().format('g:i:s A'));
},
interval: 1000 //1 second
}
Ext.TaskManager.start(task);
```

You can add your conditions to start and stop

Comment: thanx for reply sir...Its working correctly. Actually i wanted to display downcounter on view in such a way that if i set time of 40 seconds then it should decreament counter from 40. And at same time display it on view. So how to perform this in extjs4

Comment: I am not good enough to solve this but not sure it may help you [Try this](http://forums.ext.net/showthread.php?10440-CLOSED-Callback-from-a-PartialView)